# LLVM IO Error - Error writing to a bc file

Tags: c++, ios, llvm

Error occurs when I try to delete `raw_ostream`

```
void LLVMGenerator::SaveModule(string path) {

    std::string ErrInfo = "";
    llvm::raw_ostream *out =
        new llvm::raw_fd_ostream(path.c_str(), ErrInfo, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
    llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(_mod, *out);

    out->flush();
    delete out; // LLVM ERROR: IO failure on output stream.

    return;
}
```

OS Ubuntu 13.10 x64, LLVM 3.4

Comment: The first problem you have, even though it's unrelated to your problem, is that you're using a pointer. There's really no need for a pointer and `new` in that code. In fact, in C++ you should try to avoid pointers as much as you can. Also note that the destructor calls `flush` for you.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I just copy some code from BrainF LLVM example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some IO error occurred on the `raw_fd_ostream` object - perhaps the underlying `writev` call encountered a non-recoverable error. `raw_fd_ostream`'s behavior in this case is to turn on a flag indicating an error has occurred, and if that flag is still on during destruction, it reports a fatal error (=crashes).

If you want to avoid this crash, you can call `clear_error()` on the object before you destruct it; though it's of course recommended that you first check whether an error occurred yourself, via `has_error()`, and try to handle it.